# How to convert currency Strings from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which holds a list of array and the value is in 'dollars'.
I need to take the max price and min price from that list.

This is what have tried,

```
var _array = [$1.09,$3.07,$2.223];
var number = Number(_array.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
a= Math.max.apply(Math,number); // $3
b= Math.min.apply(Math,number); // $1
```

But its not working, can anyone please help me out.

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/esp41xxz/1/)

Comment: The first character of your array elements isn't a number, making them strings. They need to be quoted, otherwise you (should) have a syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is you are having illegal characters in your array. Have them like strings by wrapping in `''`.

Do it like bellow

```
var _array = ['$1.09','$3.07','$2.223'];
var numbers = _array.map(function(curr){
    return Number(curr.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""))
})
a= Math.max.apply(Math,numbers); // 3
b= Math.min.apply(Math,numbers); // 1
console.log(a,b)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/esp41xxz/2/)

**NOTE:-** The `.map` function won't work on IE8 so you can use `for` loop there. Like bellow

```
var _array = ['$1.09','$3.07','$2.223'];
var numbers = [];

for(var i=0;i<_array.length;i++){
    numbers.push(_array[i].replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
}

a= Math.max.apply(Math,numbers); // 3
b= Math.min.apply(Math,numbers); // 1
console.log(a,b)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/esp41xxz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be simple if you correct the error in your list array sort is your friend

```
var _array = ["$1.09", "$3.07", "$2.223"];
_array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Number(a.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")) - Number(b.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
});

console.log(_array[0], "   ", _array[_array.length - 1]);
```

Open your browser inspector and run the above code.

Thanks to @Meze for his contribution that makes 10.01 higher than 2 or the likes

Comment: Nice idea but not really as sorting of strings will be done alphabetically so `"$10.0"` will be before `"$2.0"`...

Comment: Yes, as long as it has common currency as $ and all the list has $. It will be seen as ["01.09","03.07","02.223"]; because $ will also evaluate to the same Unicode character. Remember that the actual sorting is perform on the Unicode character and not the numbers you see

Comment: You can solve it by passing a callback: `_array.sort(function (a, b) { return Number(a.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")) - Number(b.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")); });`

Comment: Try it with `["$10.09", "$1.12", "$3.07","$2.223"]` array.

Comment: @meze It looks interesting but I think is it an over kill. If you actually understand the sorting algorithm you will agree with with me that the replace is not required. You can subject it under test then will agree with me that as long as all the list contents has the same prefix. We might not need the replace

Comment: @Paullo It's not overkill. it's required to compare "10" and "2".