# How to avoid Text and hyphen when converting currency-strings-from-array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, data-conversion

Already posted a question [Previous Asked Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285154/how-to-convert-currency-strings-from-array)

The replies from the above question works fine, but am having a concern regarding my array.

Previous Question array and this array has some difference.

Example Array:

```
var newArray = ['$100-$129','Abcd is abcd','$20','$30.0987']
```

I need to just avoid alphabets and $ symbol only. Hyphen should remain same.
From the new array I need to take the max value and min value.
Can anyone please help me out how to achieve this on new array.

Comment: You want to find the array elements with the smallest/greatest values? What should happen in the case of `['$0-$4000','$250']`, where *one* array element has both the smallest *and* the greatest?

Comment: @DavidThomas: That is where I have stucked

Comment: So that's the problem, then; but what should happen? What result do you want?

Comment: @DavidThomas: A solution that should get the accurate min and max values. If you see my array you may find aplhabets and $ symbol which should get ignore. but the price range $0-$4000 should not get ignored

Comment: Fine. Look: given the array: `['$400', '$20', '$50-$600']` what specific precise output do you want? *Show* us what you want us to do. Explain as well, please, but take the time to show us, the *precise* output/result you want to achieve.